# How to make new pages without repeating everything? (PHP,CSS,HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm a newbie to "coding", so excuse me if my title describes this situation totally wrong or I just say stupid things.  I've read a few similar questions but I still don't get it!

My question: How do I create new pages, without having to repeat every standard sidebar 'widget', the header, menu, footer etcetera? For example, I want to create an 'About' page, but how do I even start?! I only want to change the content in the middle of the page (that is where the text is supposed to be).

The folders/files in my public_html folder are:

- _javascript (contains test, src & lib)
- _images (contains all the images obviously)
- _css (contains index.html file and global.css file)
- index.php (HTML)
- bg.php (you can just exclude this from the list, it's for creating auto-repeating bg)

Maybe it's like creating a new .php file so I can link /about.php in the menu -- but then I need to put every header & footer stuff back in there again, or maybe what I'm saying is totally wrong... It may be simple or very hard; please help me out.

Comment: Move it out into their own files, ie just header.php and footer.php, and then include them before/after your view. You could also create a function that does this for you and just call it in your file where you want your view to show. ie `<?php require_once 'common.php'; /* some logic */ renderView('thisPageName');`where common.php contain commno stuff, like a db connection, and of course the renderView function (that just includes header/thisPageName/footer .php

Comment: @JimL ...ohh okay. thank you, I will try. *will be a bit hard though..if i make that header.php where do i put it so visitors cant just access it? or is it already there, that file?

Comment: You can store php files "outside" the public_html directory on the web server. If you create an "app" folder (whichever name you want) at the same level as public_html you can place whichever files you want in there, and include them with `../app/common.php`, `../app/views/header.php` and similar. Visitors can only directly access files that are available in the public_html dir. Note that public_html might be called something else on different hosts. But it's where your website is stored today. So one folder up from that dir

Comment: `include` statement takes away a part of script just for convenience, readability and reusability while code works exactly as if included section written in the place of `include` statement. Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. And for later, you can take a look at PHP 'templating engines'  which are more convenient to use.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php for that with very small changes in your pages.

1. Change extension of your pages from .html to .php
2. Create a file header.php and paste all the header elements there.
3. do the same thing for sidebar and footer and name them as sidebar.php and footer.php or whatever you want.

Now create your pages like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
     include(header.php);
     include(sidebar.php);
?>
<div>Your contents here</div>
<?php
     include(footer.php);
?>
```

By using this ,You need not to write the code for header and all stuff again and again on every page. You can use the same technique for css and js as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create header and footer separate  as pages. Then include it in other pages. This saves time and minimizes duplication.
You can do the same for repeating stylesheets and javascripts too. Thus you only need to edit the middle section of pages.

[image]

Comment: what about the sidebar widgets and the menu? can i just find those codes in the index.php file?

Comment: create sidebar.php file, add all your sidebar html codes in it. Then wherever you want sidebar, use php include"sidebar.php"  :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

As JimL said, the most easy way to do this, is to exclude everything from the main php file, that you may need more than once. This has two main advantages:
- It makes the project easier to maintain
- The files that get used multiple times have to be loaded by the browser just once

From your project structure I conclude, that you know how to exclude JS and css so for php/html it goes like this:

- Put just the snippet you want to use several times into its own file (eg about.php)
- Use the snippet whenever you want with: `<?php include "about.php" ?>`
- Be happy about less work in the future!

Comment: This works for ANY part of your page. Just include it where needed.

Comment: @Melissa Lockwood Dont forget to choose the answer that helped you most by selecting it via the green checkmark to the left :)

Comment: Oh I totally forgot haha, I'm on it.